# Schedule something to happen 24 hours later

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script which I use to give users local admin permission for their computers, by inputting their username and computer name, which then creates a special AD-group for their computer. I usually remove the group myself in 24 hours.

My question now is, is there any way to have a piece of code scheduled to run in exactly 24 hours and remove the user from the group?

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $userName -Member $ADGroup -Confirm:$False
```

I've done some research about this and found that there are some ways to do this in Windows Server 2016, sadly we're on Windows Server 2012.

Is there some way to create a Task Scheduler event for the specific user being removed from the group?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically? Do you want your script to automatically create a scheduled task that removes the AD group?

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 86400
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-6

might not be best practices.

Answer (score 0):

why not have a script that runs every day on your server that remove members from the group where their last modified date is greater than 24hrs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that would dynamically generate a scheduled task to run another script that would do the removal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask

The trigger would need to be set for 24 hours in the future, as opposed to logon in the example, but otherwise it should be straight forward.

Also, I would recommend setting the removal script to accept the user's username as a parameter.